# How to remove # from Angular UI-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using state provider and I enabled html5 by using locationprovider and added bse tag in index file. But it's not working.

Comment: I already tried the solution but it's not working.I am using $stateprovider

Comment: Please see the code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gp80crnL/)

Comment: @VenkateshParuchuri link is working. Check my answer, little bit different, but sames components are used

Comment: @VenkateshParuchuri u saw that? https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config your app with $locationProvider:

```js
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    
    // Routes
 }
```

And HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

hashPrefix removes the '!'

Source : https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Thank You @HugoTor

Comment: Hope it's working for you :)

Comment: This is working .The # is gone form URl and when i refresh the page the url is not working.getting page not found error

Comment: Server side issue, check this comment for .htaccess config : https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag#comment-2966856314